# Why am I having NameError from a global variable I defined in my code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use the variable 'action' in another method under the Person1 class but it keeps giving a NameError.

```
import random

message_box= []
shared_files_box= []

class Chat():
    def __init__(self):
        x= ['Online', 'Offline']
        self.availability=random.choice(x)


class Message():

    def __init__(self,):
        # 0 means Sent, 1 means Not Sent, 2 means delivered, 3 means read
        self.y=[0,1,2,3]
        self.message_status=random.choice(self.y)



class Person1(Chat,Message):

    def __init__(self):
        Chat.__init__(self)
        Message.__init__(self)
        self.name = input(" Enter Username: ").upper()
        self.phone_num = "08023416789"
        prefix = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','J','Z']
        suffix = random.randint(1111, 9999)
        self.user_ID = []
        my_choice= random.choice(prefix)
        for j in my_choice:
            x= j + str(suffix)
            self.user_ID.append(x)
        



    def __str__(self):

        return "Username: {}, Phone Number: {}, User ID: {}, Availability: {}".format(self.name,self.phone_num,self.user_ID,self.availability)


    def message_to_send(self):
        global action
        print("Press 1 to send text message\nPress 2 to share file")
        action=int(input("Please what do you want to do ? "))
        return action

    def file_types(self):
        file_type = ['Audio', 'Video', 'Voice Notes', 'text message' 'other files']
        share_files = random.choice(file_type)
        return share_files

    def sendMessageFormats(self):


        if self.availability== 'Online':

            if action == 1:
                self.text_message_entry = input("Insert text message: ")
                if self.message_status== 0:
                    print(self.text_message_entry, "sent successfully !!!!!!!!")
                else: print(" Message not sent. Try again !!!!")

            elif action == 2: # You are ready to share files

                if self.message_status== 0:
                    print(self.file_types(), "sent successfully !!!!!!!!")
                else: print(" Message not sent. Try again !!!!")


            else: print("Choose between options 1 OR 2 : ")
        else: print(self.name,"You are Offline, On your data please and try again") # Data is not yet on so user is offline

    def receiveMessageFormats(self):
        if self.availability == 'Online' :
            if action ==1:
                message_box.append(self.message_to_send())
                print(message_box)

            elif action ==2:
                shared_files_box.append(self.file_types())
                print(shared_files_box, "received")

            print("Message received and Read: {}".format(self.sendMessageFormats()))


        elif self.availability == 'Online' and  self.message_status==2 :
            return "Message Delivered but not Read: {}".format(self.sendMessageFormats())

        else:
            return "Message not Read: {}".format(self.sendMessageFormats())


p=Person1()
p.receiveMessageFormats()
```

The output my IDE gives me is seen below:

```
NameError: name 'action' is not defined
```

Comment: Using global variables like that in a class defeats one of the main purposes of a class: to encapsulate mutable state.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, but I tried also to used the returned value from message_to_send() in sendMessageFormats() and receiveMessageFormats but it keeps asking me to input value  again and again.

Comment: then use an attribute

Comment: do u mean something like "instance of a class". variable ?

Comment: Check the [section on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Very first sentence of very first paragraph defines a class, and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In `sendMessageFormats` and `receiveMessageFormats` you reference the `action` variable before its defined (python assumes local scope, so you'd have to use the `global` keyword in these functions let the language know you want the global variable and not some local variable you forgot to define).

See [https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20a%20variable%20declared,variable%20is%20created%20in%20Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20a%20variable%20declared,variable%20is%20created%20in%20Python). for a greater explanation.

Also, globals are 99/100 not the right pattern.  If you can figure out a good way not to use globals in a given scenario, its usually better not do use them unless there's a compelling reason.

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried using the global keyword in those functions and its still giving the same error.

Comment: You'd need to provide more information then.  What line number is is that error occurring on?

Comment: Line 80: if action == 1:

Comment: and you had `global action` at the top of that function?

Comment: Yes I added that because the inital global I defined from message_to_send(self) did not work in that function/ method.